# What do you typically use to launch a drawer component?

Tags: buttons, conventions, actions, drawer, navigation-drawer

Outside of a hamburger menu, which is conventionally expected to open a drawer, is there another common treatment for initiating a drawer component on a page? A button? A link? Something else? Is placement and copy of the button or link important?

Concerned I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

On mobile devices, I've noticed also a horizontal slide to show the side menu (same can be done for vertical ones, but you would need somehow to visualize that feature for the user e.g. with subtle glow animation or something from the top of the screen).

Also, in material design I've seen the floating bubble/circle to call the menu.